# What is the meaning of the sentence in bold? How to analyze its tense

Tags: meaning-in-context

> <@1.1>It's only 4 hours flying time from Sydney, but a world
>   away.<@1.2>What better place to rest than a country where the only
>   place people hurry is on the football field and ***things are done in
>   "Fiji time"?***
>
> <@2.1>Viti Lev-Great Fiji-is the largest island.<@2.2>Here you'll find
>   the capital Suva and the international airport at Nadi Vatoa, on the
>   other hand, is a tiny island in the farthest part of Hiji.<@2.3>Then
>   there are 331 other islands, many of them with places to stay.
>
> <@3.1>With less than a million people living on islands, you'll never
>   feel crowded.<@3.2>And with a climate（气候）that changes only for five
>   degrees between seasons, there's never a bad time to come.
>
> <@4.1>From cities to villages, from mountains to beaches, from water
>   sports to wooden artworks, Fiji can give you more adventures and
>   special experiences than you could find almost any where in the world.
>
> <@5.1>Whenever you come , wherever you go ,you're sure to see some
>   unforgettable events , From war dances to religious （宗教的）
>   songs.<@5.2>From market days to religious days.<@5.3>It's not just
>   staged  for tourists; it's still a part of everyday life in Fiji And
>   any one of us can enjoy Fiji's spirit by being part of the traditional
>   （传统的） sharing of yaqona-a drink made from the root of a Fiji plant
>
> <@6.1>So why not join us for the experience of a lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

Literally, the phrase *things are done in "Fiji time"* means that *[people who live there] do things in "Fiji time"*. This suggests that Fiji people do things in some unique way.

***Fiji time*** refers to the time people spent in Fiji.

As the previous part of the phrase suggests, Fiji is the only place where *"the only place people hurry is on the football field"*. This means that they don't rush things in life (except on the football field). Staying in Fiji must be very casual and easygoing.

What a good place to stay and enjoy your vacation!

Answer (score 0):

***Someplace*** **time** is a phrase used to show that a geographic location is using a different time from another geographic location

> Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) *(+0 [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time))*
>   Eastern Standard Time (EST) *(+5 UTC)*
>   Daylight Savings Time (DST or [BST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst))

that it is a particular [**time zone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) which uses a specified time to coordinate activities

**Things are done in Fiji time** is a colloquial expression meaning Fiji is **metaphorically** in its own time zone. It is used to **contrast the rhythm and speed things happen** in Fuji compared to the rest of the world.  The writer is saying that things **happen** at a more **laid back**, **slower**, and **relaxed** pace in Fiji versus Sydney (in the example), which is a large bustling city.

This is characterised by being

> a world away *(from Sydney)*

where

> the only place people hurry is on the football field

and answers the question

> What better place to rest

This is in contrast to **New York** time

> [New York Minute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Minute)

where time is at a premium in the [**city that never sleeps**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_That_Never_Sleeps) and people are constantly rushing around just to stay in place and not fall behind.